# Use of the terms "queues", "multicore", and "threads" in Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: multithreading, queue, grand-central-dispatch, terminology

I am trying to get my head around the concepts of Grand Central Dispatch. I want to understand these quotes from Vandad's book on Concurrent Programming.

> The real use for GCD is to **dispatch tasks to multiple cores**, without making you the programmer, worry about which core is executing which task.

and

> At the heart of GCD are dispatch queues. **Dispatch queues are pools of threads**.

and finally

> You will not be working with these **threads** directly. You will just work with dispatch queues, **dispatching tasks to these queues** and asking queues to invoke your task.

I have bolded the key terms.

Are multiple cores the same as queues? Does a queue consist of many threads? Does each thread perform a task?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> So multiple cores are the same as queues?

Not really. A queue is a programming abstraction, a core is a physical resource in your processor. There is no unique relationship between a queue and a core, although at any given point in time it can be said that a given queue is executing a given task on a given core.

> A queue consists of many threads?

A queue consists of tasks. Tasks are assigned to threads by the queue managing system when it comes the time to execute that task. Threads are OS resources and are allocated to cores, which effectively run them and have no notion of what a task is (except for Hyper-Threading CPUs).

If you do not account for hardware-multithreading (e.g., Hyper-threading), at any given point in time a core is running a specific thread; when it comes the time to run a different thread, a context-switch occurs in that core. If you account for hardware-multithreading, you can have multiple threads running on virtual cores hosted in the same physical core.

The relationship between queues and threads is opaque. A queue could manage several threads at once, or several threads once at a time, or just one all the time; in the first case, you have a parallel queue, able to execute parallel tasks on simultaneous threads; in the second and third case, you have a serial queue.

> Each thread performs a task?

At any given point in time, a thread is performing a task. You can have threads that are spawn, execute their task, and die; or you can have long running threads (i.e., the main thread) that execute several tasks.

Maybe it is pretty puzzling at start, you might need some reading about Operating Systems and maybe high-level Processor Architectures to fully understand this.

GCD aims at letting you reason exclusively in abstract terms: i.e., in terms of tasks and queues, and forget about threads and cores, that are seen as a sort of "implementation means", or low-level details that you can leave to the system to use efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for a perfect explanation!

Comment: Is one (or more) thread(s) running within a queue or is one (or more) queue(s) running within a thread (in terms of object relation)?

Answer (score 1):

Queues are just list of tasks to execute, cores depend on the processor, you can have 1 or many cores.
Queues are configurable and you can decide if tasks can be executed concurently or not, if you allow concurency in your queue, tasks in the queue can be executed at the same time in different cores.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure those quotes really do GCD justice.  For example, to take each quote in turn:

1. GCD is more than useable (and useful) even if you have only a single core available, since multi-threading certain tasks have their place in computer science regardless of the number of physical CPU cores available.  Better to think of it as an alternative to managing threads explicitly - GCD will do the thread management so you don't have to, you (as the programmer) just have to think in terms of queues and whether certain related tasks must be done serially or can be done concurrently.
2. Dispatch queues are not "pools of threads".  Dispatch queues are "units of work aggregation" and should be thought of that way.  How that work is physically performed, by one thread or multiple threads, is not the programmer's concern and, in fact, the less assumptions the programmer makes about that the better since GCD tries very hard to be efficient and use as *few* threads as possible while still effectively utilizing hardware resources.

The third quote is good - that is the appropriate idiom to embrace.  Just submit your work (be it blocks or function/context tuples) to the appropriate queue, creating queues as necessary to associate with resources that require synchronization, and you've got the gist of GCD.