# Understanding Threads Swift

Tags: multithreading, swift

I sort of understand threads, correct me if I'm wrong.

- Is a single thread allocated to a piece of code until that code has completed?
- Are the threads prioritised to whichever piece of code is run first?
- What is the difference between main queue and thread?

My most important question:

Can threads run at the same time? If so how can I specify which parts of my code should run at a selected thread?

Comment: Your most important question is quite vague, what exactly do you mean by running at the same time ? Other than that I feel like your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166246/what-is-the-difference-between-thread-and-queue-in-ios-development which is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202789/use-of-the-terms-queues-multicore-and-threads-in-grand-central-dispatch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me start this way. Unless you are writing a special kind of application (and you will know if you are), forget about threads. Working with threads is complex and tricky. Use dispatch queues… it's simpler and easier.

Dispatch queues run tasks. Tasks are closures (blocks) or functions. When you need to run a task off the main dispatch queue, you call one of the `dispatch_` functions, the primary one being `dispatch_async()`. When you call `dispatch_async()`, you need to specify which queue to run the task on. To get a queue, you call one of the `dispatch_queue_create()` or `dispatch_get_`, the primary one being `dispatch_get_global_queue`.

---

NOTE: Swift 3 changed this from a function model to an object model. The `dispatch_` functions are instance methods of `DispatchQueue`. The `dispatch_get_` functions are turned into class methods/properties of `DispatchQueue`

---

```
// Swift 3
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    var calculation = arc4random()
}

// Swift 2
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    var calculation = arc4random()
}
```

The trouble here is any and all tasks which update the UI **must** be run on the main thread. This is usually done by calling `dispatch_async()` on the main queue (`dispatch_get_main_queue()`).

```
// Swift 3
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    var calculation = arc4random()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("\(calculation)")
    }
}

// Swift 2
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    var calculation = arc4random()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("\(calculation)")
    }
}
```

---

The gory details are messy. To keep it simple, dispatch queues manage thread pools. It is up to the dispatch queue to create, run, and eventually dispose of threads. The main queue is a special queue which has only 1 thread. The operating system is tasked with assigning threads to a processor and executing the task running on the thread.

---

With all that out of the way, now I will answer your questions.

- Is a single thread allocated to a piece of code until that code has completed?

**A task will run in a single thread.**

- Are the threads prioritised to whichever piece of code is run first?

**Tasks are assigned to a thread. A task will not change which thread it runs on. If a task needs to run in another thread, then it creates a new task and assigns that new task to the other thread.**

- What is the difference between main queue and thread?

**The main queue is a dispatch queue which has 1 thread. This single thread is also known as the main thread.**

- Can threads run at the same time?

**Threads are assigned to execute on processors by the operating system. If your device has multiple processors (they all do now-a-days), then multiple threads are executing at the same time.**

- If so how can I specify which parts of my code should run at a selected thread?

**Break you code into tasks. Dispatch the tasks on a dispatch queue.**

Comment: Thanks so much, the best help anyone has ever given me.